# Will overrides be called when class instance was send as if it was type with out overrides?

Tags: c++, oop, class, virtual

Having Class B that extends class A and overrides its functions can we be sure that when sending instance of (B*) as if it were type (A*) our overrides we created in class B will be called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the method on `A` is defined as virtual this will be the case for both pointers and references.  For example

```
class A {
  virtual void Method() {
    cout << "A::Method" << endl;
  }
};

class B {
  // "virtual" is optional on the derived method although some
  // developers add it for clarity
  virtual void Method() {
    cout << "B::Method" << endl;
  }
};

void Example1(A* param) {
  param->Method();
}

void Example2(A& param) {
  param.Method();
}

void main() {
  B b;
  Example1(&b);  // Prints B::Method
  Example2(b);   // Prints B::Method
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the functions are declared `virtual` - see http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

Only if the function in A is declared `virtual`. When declared `virtual`, any overriden child functions are called even when cast as a parent class.